# How to include Voting Button in Outlook Mail in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, outlook

I'm fairly new to VB and I have created an email to be sent to a recipient which is coded in vb from the example; [How to: Programmatically Create an E-Mail Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms269113.aspx)

```
  private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateMailItem();
    }

    private void CreateMailItem()
    {
        Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)
            this.Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
        mailItem.Subject = "This is the subject";
        mailItem.To = "someone@example.com";
        mailItem.Body = "This is the message.";
        mailItem.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceLow;
        mailItem.Display(false);
    }
```

Furthermore, I briefly looked at the Outlook MAPI refrence today since it's used in my office but I'm confused on how to proceed.

What I want to include in the email is a voting button e.g Approve/Reject so I can filter the received email from the Recipient based on the subject "Approve: blabla" using the MAPI .

P.S Outlook gives the subject title of the response in either "Approve:blasddd" or "Reject:hjjkkkk" . Please any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `MailItem.VotingOptions` property. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff424466.aspx

Comment: This answer can only be applied using C#. can we use it for vb? So far I only get errors using the "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application" library.... said it's not a member. then when I added it, it still cant be referenced.

Comment: Which particular line are you having problems translating to VB? Do include your code that you have tried

Comment: Modified the code to make it work on vb. However I reached a deadend. I havent got it to work because of forward compatibility issues. Apparently, this code will only work on Outlooks version 2013 and below, the emails I will send should be sent to Outlook 2016.

Comment: What are the compatibility issues? Are you getting a particular error?