# How to set VotingOptionData to Approve;Decline"

Tags: vb.net, email

This post is a continuation from [How to include Voting Button in Outlook Mail in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38839914/5274722) but I have made some slight change to the way I approach this problem. I'm currently using the `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data` namespace so far I have been able to create a message with this line of code below but my challenge is including the VotingOption to the email as the Namespace as `VotingInformation` and `VotingOptionData` sealed classes to deal with VotingOption bit.  I can only use these classes on emails received containing the voting choice data. Please how do I achieve this?

```
Try
    Success = True
    Dim EM As New EmailMessage(service)
    Dim Names as String()
    'To
    Names = EmailTo.Split(";")
    For Each S as String in Names
        If S <> "" Then EM.ToRecipients.Add(S)
    Next
    'CC
    Names = EmailCC.Split(";")
    For Each S as String in Names
        If S <> "" Then EM.CcRecipients.Add(S)
    Next
    'Bcc
    Names = EmailBCC.Split(";")
    For Each S as String in Names
        If S <> "" Then EM.BccRecipients.Add(S)
    Next
    'Subject
    EM.Subject = EmailSubject
    'Body
    EM.Body = EmailBody
    'Attachments
    If AttachmentPath <> "" Then
        'Split attachment paths using pipe character
        Names = AttachmentPath.Split("|")
        For Each S as String in Names
            If S <> "" Then EM.Attachments.AddFileAttachment(S)
        Next
    End If
    'Voting Options
    'Save
    EM.Save(FolderToSaveIn)
Catch ex as Exception
    Success = False
    ErrorMessage = ex.ToString()
End Try
```

P.S the service is given by my company and as such I can't attach it to this post.

Comment: Any reason you tagged this as C#?

Comment: @DavidG Sorry, I have made amends